# what does cd /./ does in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I tried just for fun doing `cd /./` in gnome-terminal and the `~` before `$` disappeared and `/` appeared instead.

for example:

```
username@machinename:~$
```

changed into

```
username@machinename:/$
```

What did it do? 
It doesn't change directory's after that happened.
I am new to GNU/linux.

Comment: It changes your current directory to `/` (root)

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com is the place to ask general questions about Unix/Linux. SO is for programming questions.

Comment: In any directory, `.` is that directory. So `/.` is the same as `/`. Adding an extra `/` to the end of a directory just refers to the directory.

Comment: try command `pwd` to see your current directory, see how it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you changed directories, from your home directory (~) to the root directory (/).

`/./` is the same as `/.`, which is the same as `/`.

Comment: thanks, that pretty much sums it up.